# Child Entities not Updating/Adding .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm creating a web app that holds questions with multiple answers using .NET Core and Entity Framework.
Currently working on the Add new and Update methods for my Question entity and I have a form on my razor page that works fine for the Question part but the Answer entity is not adding/updating.

The structure of the entities is a One to Many relationship with each Question having 4 answers linked to it. The code for the entities is as follows :

```cs
public class Question
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string QuestionBody { get; set; }
    public List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
    public QuestionTypeID QuestionTypeID { get; set; }
    public QuestionType QuestionType { get; set; }

    public Question()
    {
        Answers = new List<Answer>();
    }
}

public class Answer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string AnswerBody { get; set; }
    public Boolean IsTrue { get; set; }
    public Question Question { get; set; }
    public int QuestionID { get; set; }
}
```

I'm brand new to .NET and having to teach myself as part of my dissertation so unsure as to why the Question is storing/updating in the DB fine but the answers do not seem to be attaching to the entity and are not updating the DB.

Here is the form :

```
<form method="post">
  <input type="hidden" asp-for="Question.ID" />
  <div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Question.QuestionBody"></label>
    <input asp-for="Question.QuestionBody" class="form-control" />
    <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Question.QuestionBody"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-form-label">
    Answers
    @{
      var count = 0;
      while (@Model.newQuestion && count < EditModel.MaxAnswerLength)
      {
        <input asp-for="@Model.Question.Answers" class="form-control" />
        <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Answer"></span>
        <br />
        count++;
      }
    }

    @foreach (var answer in Model.Question.Answers)
    {
      <div class="form-group">
        <input asp-for="@answer.AnswerBody" class="form-control" />
        <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Answer.AnswerBody"></span>
      </div>
    }

  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Question.QuestionTypeID"></label>
    <select asp-for="Question.QuestionTypeID" class="form-control" asp-items="Model.QuestionTypes">
      <option></option>
    </select>
    <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Question.QuestionTypeID"></span>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
  <a asp-page="List" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</a>
</form>
```

and the OnPost method:

```cs
public IActionResult OnPost()
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        QuestionTypes = htmlHelper.GetEnumSelectList<QuestionTypeID>();
        return Page();
    }


    if (Question.ID > 0)
    {
        questionData.UpdateQuestion(Question);
    }
    else
    {
        questionData.AddQuestion(Question);
    }

    questionData.Commit();

    TempData["Message"] = "Question Saved!";
    return RedirectToPage("./Detail", new { QuestionID = Question.ID });
}
```

I'm not that familiar with EF so I have tried to create a method for AddQuestion which simply contains the below :

```cs
public Question AddQuestion(Question question)
{
    db.Questions.Add(question);
    return question;
}
```

The Update method has not been implemented yet as anything I tried did not work so thought best to start with the add then repurpose what I can when I get it working.

I believe the issue may be somewhere in the form but I'm also not sure if I'm missing something that should be in this Add method regarding adding the Answers specifially so any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on `OnPost` and step through the code does `Question.Answers` contain the answers (just before the Commit())?

Comment: Unfortunately no, shows a count of 0

Comment: Maybe this will help... https://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

Comment: @madreflection Thanks for this! I've found it hard finding references for non MVC apps but this is a bit clearer than most I've read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using a list you need indexes and with `foreach` loop you cannot accomplish that in the view. Instead try using `for`:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Question.Answers.Count; i++)
{
    <div class="form-group">
      <input asp-for="Question.Answers[i].AnswerBody" class="form-control" />
      <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Question.Answers[i].AnswerBody"></span>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Perfect, Thank you! Hadn't come across indexes for this but it now makes everything else make sense, really appreciated